# Capitalization of titles starting with chemical name with noncapitalizable prefix

Tags: discussion, question-titles

There is no question about if the first letter of the question [title should be capitalized](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3776/544).

However, there are situations, when the capitalization of the very first first character is not possible, which however does not mean, that the capitalization should not occur at all. In many (most?) cases, the capitalization should occur at the first Latin letter, that is not part of a special prefix.

Usual cases are titles **starting with a chemical name** (or related term)

- **starting with a digit**
  Example: [2-Bromo-1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene reacts with sodium ethoxide](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/72847/544)
  External example: [1,3-Dipolar cycloaddition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,3-Dipolar_cycloaddition)
- **containing Greek or other non-Latin script prefix**
  Example: [α,β-Unsaturated carbonyl compounds and alkyl addition](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/57494/544) (TODO: FIX the title)
  External example: [α,β-Unsaturated carbonyl compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonyl_group#%CE%B1,%CE%B2-Unsaturated_carbonyl_compounds)
- **containing lowercase and italicised prefix**
  Examples: [p-Nitrophenol and sodium bicarbonate test](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/74558/544) (TODO: FIX the title),
  [p-Phenylenediamine Production Process](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24568/544) (TODO: FIX the title)
  It might not be possible to preserve entire typography in the title here at SE, however we still should preserve the case, I think.
  For cis-/trans- starting titles, we should differentiate if the initial prefix is part of the name, or a term, where the italicising does not usually occur (e.g. [Trans-hydrogenation of alkenes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/54649/544) seems OK).

Note that the proper capitalization style can be verified by the examples in the last IUPAC organic nomenclature, where the capitalization of chemical names was recommended, i.e. the 1979 version (see randomly chosen example(s) [here](https://www.acdlabs.com/IUPAC/NOMENCLATURE/79/r79_323.htm)).

Comment: There is no question that the first letter should be capitalized? My God, then an awful lot of titles need fixing. Even I myself have inconsistently applied either of no capitalization or title case to question titles, and then there are titles that are sentences instead of headlines. My point is, whatever the result of this discussion, you can probably capitalize your title however you want, and as long as it's not eye-jarring, you might get away with it.

Comment: This was posted as a question, but it does not attempt to ask a question. It should possibly be an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I am an advocate for the title being an actual question, that would circumvent the capitalisation issue completely. I think the examples you brought up use oddly specific terms, while being very mysterious about the actual question. I would say the following titles would be much better options:

- What are the major products when 2-bromo-1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene reacts with sodium ethoxide?
- Is it possible to add alkyl groups in α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compounds using secondary amines?
- Why is carbon dioxide released when p-nitrophenol and sodium bicarbonate react?
- What is the production process for p-phenylenediamine?

While I think 'Trans-hydrogenation of alkenes' is somewhat okay, it would probably benefit from a better title, too.