# Converting decimal comma to an English dot

Tags: discussion, editing

We know that $25.00$ in English is actually written as $25{,}00$ in French (and many other languages [actually](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)). Weird, but [true](http://www.syllabus.ca/en/didyouknow-en/writing-numbers-in-french-and-english/)!

Now, non-anglo users frequent our site and often write in such notation. While removing [homework](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tags from old posts, I have swapped the `,` with a `.` at least ten times, until now I realized I should ask about this on meta first to reach a consensus.

This is the [latest](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/18582/revisions) occurrence of such a conversion. In such cases, should I:

1. convert the comma to a decimal?
2. leave the comma as it is?

I am actually in favor of the first way as [SE in general](https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com) has majority of its visitors from these countries (but I don't know of Chem.SE specifically?), so it makes sense to do it the way it is for the majority of the people. I would wish to hear other views though, as there are surely use-cases I might have missed.

Comment: Dot dot dot ...........

Comment: Not only in French; actually most countries use a comma as the decimal sign.

Comment: @Loong Oh, that's cool, I corrected accordingly

Comment: This ... is a really good question.  AFAIK the official language of SE sites is English, so that's probably why the Anglophone convention for decimal/comma use has been in place ($20,000.00$, rather than $20.000,00$).  We've discussed [American vs British spellings before](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2926/), but I've never seen any explicit discussion of this.

Comment: If somebody wrote "natrium" in a question, we'd edit it to "sodium" without question, and similarly for any other foreign word. I think we should do the same for foreign numerical representations. Indeed, it seems more important for numbers, since there's much more scope for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say: **Yes, convert to English-language numerical punctuation.**

The official language of the Stack Exchange network is English, save for sites whose mission is specifically to provide content in other languages.  This has been established via [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), and the [SO blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) linked there.

Therefore, it makes the most sense to me that numerical values should be consistently formatted according to English-language conventions: $12{,}345.67$, not $12.345{,}67$ or anything else. The main exception would be for material quoted from another source that uses a different syntax convention—in that case, it would make sense to leave the numbers formatted as they are in the original source.

Implicitly, the [Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) could be argued to support this view: about halfway down, it reports some numbers and uses a period as the decimal marker:

> The number of people who speak English is nowhere near as important as
>   how many people can write it. More specifically, the number of people
>   who use their written language on the Internet can be the single most
>   telling piece of information. The #1 language of the Internet is
>   English, by a wide margin. In the chart below you can see that it is
>   almost three times as prolific as the next language.
>
> > Global Internet Usage
> >     Language - Number of users (millions)
> >
> > **English - 295.2**
> >     Chinese - 110.0
> >     Spanish - 86.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) I agree with your view. The [list](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) of countries that use the comma as a separator is Swedish, French, German, Italian, etc. - i.e. non-English speaking countries only. Since StackExchange is an English speaking "country" (well at least this community is more populated than several other countries of the world :P), so the dot separator should apply, not the comma.

Comment: Note that according to ISO as well as The International System of Units (SI), where separation into groups of three digits is used, the groups shall be separated by a small space and not by a point or a comma or by any other means; i.e. write $12\,345.67$ rather than $12{,}345.67$.

Comment: @Loong But, do we use the English conventions or the SI conventions for this matter? I think this is a borderline case, as the separation of three-digit-groups by a space/comma falls under the jurisdiction of both the SI units (as you said) and the English language. Both have opposite recommendations, so which to choose?

Comment: @GaurangTandon I don't think we need to specify English or ISO as a strict convention. mwchem has conveniently included the ISO half-space separator in the `\pu` "physical units" helper command within the `mwchem` `\ce` environment: `$\ce{\pu{20000}}%` $\rightarrow \ce{\pu{20000}}$. So, in math and formulas, where the ISO formatting is easily available, one can use that. In regular text, where a half-space is hard to achieve, sticking with the English "20,000" would be fine.

Comment: Yes, that sounds helpful @hBy2Py :)

Comment: Consider adding Loong's update into your answer. I'll accept your answer within a week until there any contradictory views.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yep, will do,, I was planning to edit it into the answer after a bit as long as there wasn't any major pushback.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I'd suggest that editing to "correct" English to ISO is basically the same as editing to "correct" British to American spelling (or vice-versa).